# Solving equation for unknown and replacing it in second equation

Tags: equation-solving, variable

I am new to Mathematica and struggling with its syntax.
I have a set of equations,  which I would like to solve for my unknowns.
I would like to solve the first equation for the first unknown and substitute this unknown in a second equation with the result I have obtained from `Solve`. Sounds easy, but for me this seems to be undoable.

Here my MWE:

```
g1 = a + b + 2*c + 5 == 0
g2 = a + e + c - 5 == 0
sol = Solve[g1, c]
g2 = g2 /. c -> sol
```

The result is:

```
{{-5 + a + e + (c -> 1/2 (-5 - a - b))}} == 0
```

which is clearly not what I wanted. In the second step I want to solve `g2` for `a`, assuming `b` and `e` are known.

Comment: Try `g2/.sol` and don't overwrite `g2=g2...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

g1 = a + b + 2*c + 5 == 0;
g2 = a + e + c - 5 == 0;
```

With two equations you can solve for two unknowns.

```
sol = Solve[{g1, g2}, {a, c}]

(* {{a -> 15 + b - 2 e, c -> -10 - b + e}} *)
```

Or, if you only want to solve for `a` while eliminating `c`

```
sola = Solve[{g1, g2}, a, {c}]

(* {{a -> 15 + b - 2 e}} *)
```

For your larger system of equations, try structuring it as a minimization problem.

```
min = Minimize[Total[(Subtract @@@ {g1, g2})^2], {a, c}] // Simplify

(* {0, {a -> 15 + b - 2 e, c -> -10 - b + e}} *)
```

If an exact solution exists, the minimum is zero and the approaches are equivalent.

```
sol[[1]] === min[[2]]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you I will definitely try it. Is the chance for solving my larger problem with minimize bigger?

Comment: I have no way of knowing or even guessing. Since the approach that you are using doesn't seem to be working, it is at least an alternative.

Comment: okay, I will try it. The three @ are strange to me, so I did some research. According to Wolfram this means "Verify that their differences are integers:", but since I am seeking the symbolic solutions is thisusefull or necessary?

Comment: Okay I have to admit that the longer I look at our minimize code the less I understand it. You subtract g2 from g1 and square the result, okay I understand this. But why 'Total', where does the sum come from?

Comment: In general the equations could be of the form `lhs == rhs`, i.e., `Equal[lhs, rhs]` where `rhs` is **not necessarily** zero. Highlight `@@@` and press `F1` for help. You will go to a link for `Apply`. The documentation there states "f@@@expr or Apply[f, expr, {1}] replaces heads at level 1 of expr by f." So `Subtract @@@ eqns` results in `{lhs1-rhs1, lhs2-rhs2, ...}`. To satisfy the equations, all of these numbers must be zero. A standard way of doing this is to minimize the sum of the squares (positive numbers), i.e., minimize `Total[(Subtract @@@ eqns)^2]`

Answer (score 0):

You may use your approach after applying the correction proposed by @Ulrich Neumann. There is, however, a function specifically for such an operation:

```
g1 = a + b + 2*c + 5 == 0
g2 = a + e + c - 5 == 0

Eliminate[{g1, g2}, c]

(*    15 + b - 2 e == a  *)
```

The both approaches yield the same final equation.

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you, my real problem is a little bit more complictaed than my MWE. I have 9 non-linear equations which I would like to solve for 9 unknowns. Numerically this is no problem but I need the symbolic solutions, if they exist. Simply Solve[{equations}{unkowns}] does not work, it runs for days without a result.

Comment: My question is, is it worth trying to use Eliminate?

Comment: My experience tells me that exactly in the situation you described in some cases I could not get a solution with `Solve`, but succeeded first using `Eliminate` and after that `Solve`. In other cases it did not help. Of course, 9 nonlinear equations is a lot, and I would not be very optimistic about finding the exact solution. However, everything depends on the form of equations. I wish you to be lucky.

Comment: Nine nonlinear equations... If they are polynomials, `Solve` is most likely to be hanging either in computing a Groebner basis, or in unravelling the roots. The complexity with depend on degrees and on presence/absence of symbolic parameters. If they are polynomials and the input is not mongo-large, I will suggest posting as a new MSE question.